# How can I start Gmail (and other google applications) when I'm offline?

Tags: linux, firefox, gmail, google-gears

Using Gears, I can download my mail, calendar, etc. from Google Apps and when I disconnect from the net while the application is opened in the browser, I can still access my data. Google also places icons in my Desktop/ folder which I can use to start firefox on the correct page, but they link to "google.com" which is not available when I'm offline. Is there a way to keep a local copy of the google apps so I can start the appliactions in offline mode?

Comment: For me, when I just go to gmail.com when I am offline gears loads gmail in offline mode.

Answer (score 1):

### Gmail Offline in Gmail Labs :

in Gmail go to setting -> labs then enable the Offline feature, after that you can surf Gmail offline and even see your attchments

[image]

> Make Gmail go where the Internet
>   doesn't. Access your inbox through
>   your browser and use Gmail's familiar
>   features when you're offline. To get
>   started, enable this lab and then
>   click on the "Offline" link in the
>   upper-right of your inbox.

Comment: Is that even answering the question?

Comment: yes it does! do you see anything else?

Comment: No it doesnt ;) I already did that, but as i stated, gmail must be running - i.e. i have to go to gmail.com while i'm online and then not close the tab or browser before I lose my connection. But when I boot my lpatopt somewhere where I don't have an internet connection, I can not start the gmail application...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible with other browser than chrome. The shortcut i have leads to:

```
chrome.exe  --app=https://mail.google.com/mail/
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Firefox. I read my mail with Chrome, and I created a shortcut on my desktop (using the link in Mail - Settings - Offline - Other options). And when I click that shortcut when I'm offline, it brings me to my mailbox.

Comment: That sounds like what I want to do, I will try that. However, I'm still interested in a firefox solution as well.